# How to Have Responsive Div's That Get Wider as the Navbar Closes

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am working on a portal and I found a good calendar to throw into my web page. Right now, the css has it set up so that the first div has the attribute "left:250px" and then the "width:200px" and then my second div is set to "left:450". The problem is when I close my side navbar the divs stay stationary. I want them to be responsive and slide over the area where the navbar once was but I haven't figured out how to do that. I've tried using  but it wasn't seeming to work very well. Below are pictures of my problems for you guys to see,

Before:

[image: sidebar opened]

After:

[image: sidebar closed]

Here is my code, both the css and html. A lot of html, js and css has been left out but I think the code I linked is where the problem is going wrong. If you think the problem might be elsewhere please let me know and I can link it. Thanks for the help friends!!

```css
#lnb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 49px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  background: #fafafa;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 450px;
  top: 49px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="lnb">
  <div class="lnb-new-schedule">
    <button id="btn-new-schedule" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary 
         btn-block " data-toggle="modal">
            New schedule</button>
  </div>
  <div id="lnb-calendars" class="lnb-calendars">
    <div>
      <div class="lnb-calendars-item">
        <label>
                    <input class="tui-full-calendar-checkbox-square" 
                     type="checkbox" value="all" checked>
                    <span></span>
                    <strong>View all</strong>
                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="calendarList" class="lnb-calendars-d1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lnb-footer">
    © Noblis ESI
  </div>
</div>

<div id="right">
  <div id="menu">
    <span class="dropdown">
            <button id="dropdownMenu-calendarType" class="btn btn-default 
             btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                <i id="calendarTypeIcon" class="calendar-icon ic_view_month" 
                 style="margin-right: 4px;"></i>
                <span id="calendarTypeName">Dropdown</span>&nbsp;
    <i class="calendar-icon tui-full-calendar-dropdown-arrow"> 
                </i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria- labelledby="dropdownMenu-calendarType">
      <li role="presentation">
        <a class="dropdown-menu-title" role="menuitem" data- action="toggle-daily">
          <i class="calendar-icon ic_view_day"></i>Daily
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a class="dropdown-menu-title" role="menuitem" data- action="toggle-weekly">
          <i class="calendar-icon ic_view_week"></i>Weekly
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a class="dropdown-menu-title" role="menuitem" data- action="toggle-monthly">
          <i class="calendar-icon ic_view_month"></i>Month
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a class="dropdown-menu-title" role="menuitem" data- action="toggle-weeks2">
          <i class="calendar-icon ic_view_week"></i>2 weeks
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a class="dropdown-menu-title" role="menuitem" data- action="toggle-weeks3">
          <i class="calendar-icon ic_view_week"></i>3 weeks
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" data-action="toggle-workweek">
          <input type="checkbox" class="tui-full-calendar- 
                         checkbox-square" value="toggle-workweek" checked>
          <span class="checkbox-title"></span>Show weekends
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" data-action="toggle-start-day-1">
          <input type="checkbox" class="tui-full-calendar- 
                         checkbox-square" value="toggle-start-day-1">
          <span class="checkbox-title"></span>Start Week on Monday
        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" data-action="toggle-narrow-weekend">
          <input type="checkbox" class="tui-full-calendar- 
                          checkbox-square" value="toggle-narrow-weekend">
          <span class="checkbox-title"></span>Narrower than weekdays
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </span>
    <span id="menu-navi">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-today" 
             data-action="move-today">Today</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-day" 
             data-action="move-prev">
                <i class="calendar-icon ic-arrow-line-left" data- 
                 action="move-prev"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-day" 
                 data-action="move-next">
                <i class="calendar-icon ic-arrow-line-right" data- 
                 action="move-next"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    <span id="renderRange" class="render-range"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your CSS also.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to add it. Should be there now

Comment: Would be significantly easier to figure this out with the complete code (or just link it if you have to since it's probably a lot). The small section of code your provided doesn't give us the full picture to compare.

Comment: Yeah sure, do you have an idea of where I could post all my code? I don't want to over clutter this page because there is quite a few lines of code. Thanks for responding the help is greatly appreciated!